# Does Cloudflare support stale-while-revalidate?

Tags: caching, cloudflare, http-caching

Cloudflare documents a list of directives for the `Cache-Control` header, including [stale-while-revalidate](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003206852-Origin-Cache-Control).

> - stale-while-revalidate=<seconds>
>     When present in an HTTP response, the stale-while-revalidate Cache-Control extension indicates that caches MAY serve the response in which it appears after it becomes stale, up to the indicated number of seconds since the object was originally retrieved.

I set my `Cache-Control` header to `public, max-age=0, stale-while-revalidate=30` but I never seem to get a cache hit. Does Cloudflare actually support this?

Comment: sorry for asking here, but just saw your question and its locked https://community.cloudflare.com/t/does-stale-while-revalidate-work/24161 do you know if they are suppring it now? I tried to test and it seems they still not support it but I am not sure

Comment: @AmirBar I have just done some testing myself, and i cant get it to serve stale. I can get it to serve me a stale response IF i open another browser and hit same URL. But the initiator still doesn't get a stale response, thus it is blocked. This behaviour is the same as if you dont include the "stale-while-revalidate" setting in the Cache-Control header.

Comment: I've tried all day to get it working. Even without this header I managed to get STALE responses if I take my server down - unless I send must-revalidate. But I couldn't get stale-while-revalidate to do anything different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Cloudflare doesn't support `stale-while-revalidate`. The last word from them was in January 2022.

https://community.cloudflare.com/t/when-will-cloudflare-fully-support-stale-while-revalidate-with-asynchronous-background-revalidation/287764/9?u=dfabulich

> To begin, we agree that this feature is good for the Internet and something that we will look to implement soon. The reason this isn’t currently supported is a technical limitation stemming from long-standing technical debt. The good news is that we’re currently in the process of getting rid of these limitations so that we can safely support more async features like this one. In the meantime, I thank you for your patience and look forward to supporting this soon.

… nothing has changed since then.

Cloudflare does have a feature that looks kinda like SWR if you squint and turn your head a little, a feature where *parallel* requests can receive stale `UPDATING` content during a slow revalidation. But that feature (which *is* genuinely interesting) is on by default, and isn’t affected by the SWR header. (Even setting `stale-while-revalidate=0` doesn’t turn the feature off!)

I wrote up a lengthy analysis of Cloudflare's nonexistent SWR support in 2018, but it did me no good; Cloudflare has never directly replied to it. https://community.cloudflare.com/t/does-stale-while-revalidate-work/24161/6?u=dfabulich

Answer (score 0):

If you put `max-age=0`, then effectively nothing is cached, if so, then there is nothing to serve. Try with `max-age=1` - that should give some results in that 30 sec. period.

Comment: That's a good guess! But it doesn't work. After waiting a full second between requests, I never get a cache hit.

Comment: I have tested this with max-age=1, and a stale-while-revalidate=30. I still dont get a STALE response from Cloudflare. It seems like this is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this question / issue today, and the Cloudflare documentation is not very clear, but there is a clue under their examples section on [this page](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003206852-Understanding-Origin-Cache-Control).

> Cache-Control: max-age=600, stale-while-revalidate=30
>
> This configuration indicates the asset is fresh for 600 seconds, and can be served stale for up to an additional 30 seconds to parallel requests for the same resource while the initial synchronous revalidation is attempted.

So, Cloudflare does support the directive, however their implementation is a bit different than one might expect. Essentially the first request made to your server once the cached content is expire will result in a synchronous request to your Origin, which that client must wait for (the behavior most people don't want).

**However**, there is some support because any *parallel* requests (e.g. made by other clients) for that same resource will get the old / cached content instead (with a `CF-Cache-Status: UPDATING`). Tested this and was able to confirm behavior.

In this way, if you have a very slow origin response, or a very popular cached resource, only a single client / user is held up, and the rest get served up the stale cached copy from Cloudflare. Better than nothing.

Comment: That's not `stale-while-revalidate`. That's just Cloudflare's default behavior. That feature (which is genuinely interesting) is on by default, and isn’t affected by the SWR header. (Even setting stale-while-revalidate=0 doesn’t turn the feature off!) I did a lengthy analysis of that feature here: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/does-stale-while-revalidate-work/24161/6?u=dfabulich